# OpenGL: bind at least one texture when working with textures?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I started using textures in openGl and I noticed some strange behavior. See the following pseudo code example:

```
int main()...
bindTexture1();
bindTexture2();
bindTexture3();

// None of these textures are actually used!

while(true) {
    begin();
    // draw stuff 
    end();
}
```

Im loading and binding 3 textures but right now Im just drawing primitives. But those primitives are not visible. They are visible in the following cases:

```
int main()...
bindTexture1();   // <- So the first bind() remains the only one
//bindTexture2();
//bindTexture3();

// None of these textures are actually used!

while(true) {
    begin();
    // draw again just primitve stuff but now it's visible
    end();
}
```

Or

```
int main()...
bindTexture1();
bindTexture2();
bindTexture3();

// None of these textures are actually used!

while(true) {
    begin();
    bindTexture1();  // Binding texture 1 again
    // draw again just primitve stuff but now it's visible 
    end();
}
```

So I guess my problem is connected to this glBindTexture function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure when rendering a 2D texture in fixed pipeline (opengl 1 and 2) is this :

```
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId );

// render
glBegin( GL_QUADS );

   glTexCoord2f( 0.0, 0.0 );
   glVertex2f( 0.0, 0.0 );
   glTexCoord2f( 1.0, 0.0 );
   glVertex2f( 1.0, 0.0 );
   glTexCoord2f( 1.0, 1.0 );
   glVertex2f( 1.0, 1.0 );
   glTexCoord2f( 0.0, 1.0 );
   glVertex2f( 0.0, 1.0 );

glEnd();

glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

Comment: glEnable texture is only required for fixed function pipeline.

Comment: This answer solved my Problem. Is there any significant speed difference if you use glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D ); and glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D ); more often? E.g. for each object with a texture?   Or should i call it once, render all stuff with a texture, and call glDisable?

Comment: @Anonymous No. That would be a micro optimization